# How to address error in quartic solver in Mathematica 11

Tags: equation-solving

I want to let people know about the following problem, although I am not sure what do do about it.

The symbolic solver for quartics does not function correctly in Mathematica 11, although at least for this problem it did function correctly previously. The following calculation illustrates this.

```
eq20 = -5 - 4 A x - 3 x^4
res20 = Solve[eq20 == 0, x];
res20 /. A -> 10000.
```

Out[238]= -5 - 4 A x - 3 x^4

Out[240]= {{x -> 11.5928 - 20.5409 I}, {x -> 
   11.5928 + 20.5409 I}, {x -> -23.9679}, {x -> 0.782297}}

```
eq21 = eq20 /. A -> 10000.
res21 = Solve[eq21 == 0, x]
```

Out[241]= -5 - 40000. x - 3 x^4

Out[242]= {{x -> -23.7126}, {x -> -0.000125}, {x -> 11.8564 - 20.5357 I}, {x -> 
   11.8564 + 20.5357 I}}

This last result is the one that was given by prior versions of Mathematica, although the root order was different. Evaluation shows that the prior version was correct:

```
eq20 /. {A -> 10000., x -> 0.782297}
eq20 /. {A -> 10000., x -> -0.000125}
```

Out[245]= -31298.

Out[246]= -7.32422*10^-16

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: For me, using Mathematica 11.0.1 on Windows, I get {0,0,0,0} and I see no error: `eq20 = -5 - 4*A*x - 3*x^4; 
res20 = Solve[eq20 == 0, x]; 
eq21 = eq20 /. A -> 10000.; 
res21 = Solve[eq21 == 0, x]; 
Chop[eq20 /. A -> 10000. /. res21, 10^(-9)]` Which exact Mathematica version are you using and on which operating system?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!  When you post questions, please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag. This is a special tag that is—by agreement—always added by someone else than the original poster of the question, after the community has verified the bug.  I have removed the tag for now. If the bug is verified, the tag will be re-added.

Comment: I don't think it's the solver, it's the numerical evaluation of the solution.  Good old subtractive cancellation with `3A^2 - Sqrt[-125 + 9A^4]`.

Answer (score 5):

A mentioned in comments, no error here (in the sense of software bugs), just numeric cancellation. One way to see this is to do the substitution exactly, then numericize to higher precision than machine arithmetic allows.

```
eq20 = -5 - 4 A x - 3 x^4;
res20 = Solve[eq20 == 0, x];
N[r10k = res20 /. A -> 10000, 100] // N
ns = NSolve[eq20 /. A -> 10000]
Quiet[N[(eq20 /. A -> 10000) /. r10k, 100]] // N
eq20 /. A -> 10000 /. ns

(* Out[244]= {{x -> 11.8564 - 20.5357 I}, {x -> 
   11.8564 + 20.5357 I}, {x -> -23.7126}, {x -> -0.000125}}

Out[245]= {{x -> -23.7126}, {x -> -0.000125}, {x -> 
   11.8564 - 20.5357 I}, {x -> 11.8564 + 20.5357 I}}

Out[246]= {0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I, 0., 0.}

Out[247]= {-1.16415*10^-10, -7.32422*10^-16, 
 5.82077*10^-11 - 2.32831*10^-10 I, 5.82077*10^-11 + 2.32831*10^-10 I} *)
```

I doubt anything changed over the last few versions. If there was a change, it might have involved the form the quartic result takes, and possibly some forms are less prone to numeric error than others for this type of substitution.